# gcc windows declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration

Tags: c

I have a header file & C file placed in the same directory... The header file obviously just declares things while the C file defines them. To my understanding, this is the correct way to do it. It seems like it is not visible to the linker. (I am currently experimenting with linear probing so i know the code probably wont work when a collision occurs, but it is valid code so it should compile.)

This is the header:

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



struct Header {

    /* key will always be present */

    char* key;

    /* value can be blank / null */
    
    char* value;
    
    /* RFC conforming; index of the header so we can use a hashmap */

    int index;

};

struct HashTable {

    struct Header** headerArr;

    uint16_t size;

    /* this will start at the size of the static table then be used to fill the index field of the Header struct before being placed within the array */

    int currentDynamicIndex;


};

/* init the hash table to a given size */

uint8_t initHashTable(struct HashTable* hashTable);

/* maps a struct to a value within the hashmap */

uint32_t hash(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header);

/* add a header pair to the hash table */

uint8_t add(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header);

/* find index given a value */

int lookup(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header);

/* delete an element from the hashmap */

uint8_t delete(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header);
```

The C file includes the header file then starts defining the functions:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "hash.h"


uint32_t hash(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header) {

    /* loop over both values in the header struct and add their ascii values to get a different number each time */

    uint32_t finalNumb = 0;

    size_t strLen = strlen(header->key);

    for (size_t x = 0; x < strLen; ++x) {

        finalNumb += (int)header->key;

        finalNumb = (finalNumb * (int)header->value) % hashTable->size;

    }

    /* if the header value struct is not empty, add it too */

    if (header->value != NULL) {

        strLen = strlen(header->value);

        for (size_t x = 0; x < strLen; ++x) {

            finalNumb += (int)header->value;

            finalNumb = (finalNumb * (int)header->value) % hashTable->size;

        }
    }

    return finalNumb;

}

uint8_t initHashTable(struct HashTable* hashTable) {

    /* this needs to be set to the size of the static table + 1 (since the 0th index is not a thing in the RFC) */

    hashTable->currentDynamicIndex = 62;

    hashTable->headerArr = calloc(hashTable->size, sizeof(struct Header));

    if (hashTable->headerArr == NULL) {

        /* calloc error */

        return 0;

    }

    return 1;

}

uint8_t add(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header) {

    uint32_t index = hash(hashTable, header);

    /* check if the index is occupied first */

    if (hashTable->headerArr[index] != NULL) {

        /* its occupied so use linear probing which is just +1 */

        uint32_t newIndex = index += 1;

        while (hashTable->headerArr[newIndex] != NULL) {

            newIndex += 1;

            if (hashTable->size <= newIndex) {

                newIndex = 0;

            }
        }

        return hashTable->headerArr[newIndex];

    }

    hashTable->headerArr[index] = header;

}

int lookup(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header) {

    /* the structs that are provided wont have an index field that isnt NULL but the ones in the array will */

    uint32_t index = hash(hashTable, header);

    if (hashTable->headerArr[index] != NULL && strcmp(header->key, hashTable->headerArr[index]->key) == 0 && strcmp(header->value, hashTable->headerArr[index]->value) == 0) {

        return hashTable->headerArr[index]->index;

    }

    return -1;

}

uint8_t delete(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header) {

    uint32_t index = hash(hashTable, header);

    /* check if the index is occupied first */

    if (hashTable->headerArr[index] != NULL) {

        hashTable->headerArr[index] = NULL;
        
        return 1;

    }

    return 0;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("ok\n");

    return 1;
    
}
```

What are the possible reasons for this? All previous stack overflow answers related to this seem to be because the struct is placed AFTER the function declarations.

```
hash.c:96:19: warning: 'struct HashTable' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 int lookup(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header) {
```

```
hash.c: At top level:
hash.c:96:48: warning: 'struct Header' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 int lookup(struct HashTable* hashTable, struct Header* header) {
```

Output of -H

```
... C:/Strawberry/c/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/include/stddef.h
.... C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h
. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h
.. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sec_api/string_s.h
... C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h
. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h
.. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw_print_push.h
.. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw_off_t.h
.. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/swprintf.inl
.. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h
... C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h
.. C:/Strawberry/c/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw_print_pop.h
. hash.h
```

It does actually seem that renaming the file(s) worked. I only get some cast errors now. Solution as suggested by @Jonathan Leffler. Not sure what file would be named hash.h/.c in the c stdlib since theres no implementation of such a data structure

Comment: How do you call the linker?

Comment: gcc -c hash.c and hash.c is the name of the c file & hash.h is the name of the .h file

Comment: `gcc -c` is the compiler call. How do you call the linker?

Comment: not sure what you mean, gcc -c is as far as i can get, before it gives me these warnings/errors

Comment: What are those warnings/errors (verbatim)?

Comment: Show the exact compiler error message (it is not a linker issue) for the source code you show in the question.  Is there any danger that you are not including your `hash.h` but are including some system-defined header of the same name?  Use `gcc -H` (plus your other usual options) to see a list of the headers actually included.

Comment: see upated question

Comment: Thanks.  Please note that this is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  You should be able to eliminate all the functions defined before (and after) `lookup`, for example.  _…However…_

Comment: However, when I compile the code copied from the question with my stringent options (on macOS 12.3.1 using home-built GCC 11.2.0), I get a number of errors (warnings) but not the error you report.  This is more or less what I'd expect from reviewing the code.  I use `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common hash.c -o hash` to compile this.

Comment: This is a minimal and complete example since the structs are causing the errors and each function is giving me the warnings. Although, i did not post every single warning since its the same for each function (minimal)

Comment: The `-H` output shows that GCC is using your `hash.h` — that's good.

Comment: We only need one function that's giving the warnings.  Line 96 usually means "this is not minimal".

Comment: Anyway, the upshot is that I cannot reproduce the problem with the code in the question — not on my Mac, anyway.  Normally, the error means that the structure names have not been defined before the functions are defined (which is what you've found from your research).  But that doesn't seem to be a problem when I'm compiling.

Comment: Incidentally, the `hash.h` header should not include either `<string.h>` or `<stdlib.h>`.  None of the declarations in the header require information from either of those headers.  The `<stdint.h>` is required.  A header should be self-contained, idempotent and minimal — your header is self-contained and idempotent (with compilers that recognize `#pragma once`), but is not minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The message “warning: 'struct HashTable' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration” arises when a declaration of `struct HashTable` is first seen inside the parameter list of a function declaration. This is not a linker error; it is the compiler telling you that there is no prior declaration fo `struct HashTable` to put the structure declaration into file scope, so it is appearing only in the function. (And, due to rules about structure tags, this means that, even if a declaration for the structure appears later in file scope, it will be a different type from the one declared inside the function parameters.)

Since the “hash.h” file you show has a declaration of `struct Header` and the “hash.c” file you show includes “hash.h”, this means the compiler is not seeing the same “hash.h” that you show. Either the contents you pasted into this question are in a text editor whose contents have not yet been written to the disk file “hash.h” or there are multiple “hash.h” files and the compiler is using a different one or there is some other mismatch between the source code you pasted and what is actually being compiled. You need to investigate the files on disk and fix what is actually being compiled.